# Why can not the Compiler decide the type

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

I am just curious to know why do we need to append m or M for decimal type?

[Documentation says there is no implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I think the compiler has enough information because we declare `Decimal` key word.

Can some one please explain why can not the compiler determine the value should be treated as 
decimal but not double.

Comment: How about `var x = 12.3` or `foo(12.3)`; is 12.3 a float or decimal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a statement like this

```
decimal x = 5.6;
```

the compiler first looks only at the right-hand side of the assignment (`5.6`), determines its type (`double`)  and then checks if the result can be assigned to the variable on the left-hand side (`x`).

Since `x` is declared as `decimal` but the compiler has determined that the expression is of type `double` (and there is no implicit conversion from `double` to `decimal`), the assignment is invalid.

(The only exception to this rule is assigning a lambda expression to a delegate variable. In this case, the compiler indeed uses the information at the left-hand side to determine the type of the right-hand side.)

Comment: That explains why it works the way it does, but it doesn't explain why the compiler *couldn't* do what the OP intended (it in fact could). Subtle difference, might be worth mentioning.

Comment: What if the bug is that you declared it as Decimal when you intended a double? In that case your bug is not detected. Therefore the best a compiler can do is take you at your word and assume that a double literal is indeed intended as a double literal.